# Print the column 1 before each column of the file in new line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a data file of 1000 to 2000 columns and more than 3000 rows.

Input example Data

```
GO:0009987 Os760  Os840  Os550  Os380  Os590  Os340
GO:0043170 Os610  Os043  Os035
```

Expected Output:

```
GO:0009987 Os760  
GO:0009987 Os840  
GO:0009987 Os550  
GO:0009987 Os380  
GO:0009987 Os590
GO:0009987 Os340
GO:0043170 Os610
GO:0043170 Os043 
GO:0043170 Os035
```

I tried this:

```
sed 's/ /\n/2; P; D' filename | awk 'NF==2 {a =$1;b=$2; print; next} {print a,$0}'
```

But this give me result like this. `(with one extra GO value in column 1)`. I want to **remove this extra GO** from the file.

```
GO:0009987 Os760  
GO:0009987 Os840  
GO:0009987 Os550  
GO:0009987 Os380  
GO:0009987 Os590
GO:0009987 Os340
GO:0009987
GO:0043170 Os610
GO:0043170 Os043 
GO:0043170 Os035
GO:0043170
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(changed delimited selection as per Sundeep sir's comments).

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

OR try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":| +"} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){print $1":"$2,$i}}' Input_file
```

OR:

```
awk -F':| +' '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){print $1":"$2,$i}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice the small mistake in my input file. Otherwiswe it also work fine:

```
sed 's/ /\n/2; P; D' filename | awk 'NF==2 {a =$1;b=$2; print; next} {print a,$0}'
```